# Left Join Table and Echo in Table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display row in table from my two table. I want all row from table called teacher_profile and want name column from center. I am able to run query in phpMyAdmin and its working fine but issue is both table have name is common so I am not able to properly display centername in my table. Because there teacher_profile and center both have name column. I can not rename it because it's live and used with my Android application.

```
select *
        from teacher_profile q 
        left outer join center a on a.id = q.centerId
       ORDER BY q.id DESC
```

How can I get name column from center as center_name in result so I can use it with my table row?

Note: I want only name column from center table and want to get something like centername so there no multiple column name come in query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fully qualified column names. `q.name` is the `name` column from `teacher_profile` and `a.name` is the `name` column from the `center` table.