# Join One Column From other Table and Echo it

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two table called

`teacher_profile` which have fields like id, centerId, name, study, class etc
And

table `center` which have column like id, name, location.

I am trying to get all fields from table teacher_profile and want center name from center table with that query.

```
$qry="select * from teacher_profile AS q 
left join center AS a on a.id = q.centerId
ORDER BY q.id DESC";

$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$qry);
```

Its giving me all column from table center as well. I want only name column from it as centerName so I can display it properly in my PHP table. Let me know if someone can help me for achieve it.
Thanks

Comment: you get all because you ask for all with `*` so just specify what you want in the query

Comment: This sounds like your last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873471/left-join-table-and-echo-in-table-mysqli-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  q.* and a.center uisng alias center_name

```
    $qry="select q.*, a.center center_name from teacher_profile AS q 
            left join center AS a on a.id = q.centerId
           ORDER BY q.id DESC";
        $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$qry);
```

you can refere the the column using index   center_name

```
       echo $row['center_name'];
```

Comment: sorry sir, its giving error called Unknown column 'a.center' in 'field list'

Comment: @RajuBhatt That means you don't have a column named `center` in the `center` table. Run `show create table center` and see what your actual columns are. Then adjust accordingly. This answer should give you the basic concept to make it work with your schema. Alternatively you should be able to use the numeric indices and it would also be accessible that way. (assuming you're fetching it with the default both)

Answer (score 0):

On the query, select statement you can specify which columns you want.

see example

```
$qry="
SELECT
   center.name, teacher_profile.*
FROM 
    teacher_profile
left join center on teacher_profile.id = center.centerId
ORDER BY 
    teacher_profile.id DESC
";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$qry);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its giving error called "#1054 - Unknown column 'centerName' in 'field list'"

Comment: I Think I was have not properly asked question. Sorry, Table center have field like name which I want get with query. Can You please check my edited question again. Thanks a lot